# Failure deleting from heap

Tags: c++, c++11

I am making a string with SSO, and I want to store the pointer to the heap memory inside the stack array when the string exceeds 23 characters. The issue I am having is that I get an error when I attempt to delete the memory allocated on the heap. I know for a fact that I am calling delete on the correct address, but it fails. Would anyone know why? Code is below:

```
class kstring
{
public:
  kstring()
  {

  }

  kstring(const char* str) 
  {
    size_ = std::strlen(str);
    if (size_ + 1 > capacity_)
      reserve(capacity_ + 1);
    std::strcpy(data(), str);
  }

  void reserve(size_t capacity)
  {
    if (capacity <= capacity_ || capacity <= 24)
      return;
    char* alloc = new char[capacity];
    std::cout << "Alloc: " << static_cast<void*>(alloc) << std::endl;
    std::copy(data(), data() + size_, alloc);
    if (on_heap())
      delete[] data();
    std::memcpy(data_, &alloc, sizeof(char*));
    capacity_ = capacity;
  }

  char* data()
  {
    return capacity_ > 24 ? heap_ptr() : data_;
  }

  size_t size() const noexcept
  {
    return size_;
  }

  size_t capacity() const noexcept
  {
    return capacity_;
  }

  char& operator[](size_t n)
  {
    return data()[n];
  }

  ~kstring()
  {
    if (on_heap())
    {
      std::cout << "Deleting: " << static_cast<void*>(data()) << std::endl;
      delete[] data();
    }
  }

  bool on_heap()
  {
    return capacity_ > 24;
  }

  char* heap_ptr()
  {
    char* ptr = nullptr;
    std::memcpy(&ptr, data_, sizeof(char*));
    return ptr;
  }

  char data_[24] = {0};
private:
  size_t size_ = 0;
  size_t capacity_ = 24;
};

int main()
{
  {
    kstring str("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

SOLUTION: In the constructor, I was allocating `capacity_ + 1` bytes instead of `size_ + 1` bytes, leading to heap corruption.

Comment: Please post how you're using this class.  This class can easily be corrupted with a simple 2 line program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie edited

Comment: `char* ptr = nullptr; std::memcpy(&ptr, data_, sizeof(char*));` -- Ask yourself what the second line does, especially what the first parameter denotes.

Comment: The constructor should reserve `size + 1`, not `capacity_ + 1`.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the migration to heap actually holds onto the pointer in a member variable such that you can actually delete it later...

Comment: `{ kstring str("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"); kstring str2 = str; }` -- Even if you had the original pointer you allocated with, that piece of code fails miserably,

Comment: @PeteBecker AHA! Thank you for noticing that, you're a life saver :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `char* ptr = nullptr; std::memcpy(&ptr, data_, sizeof(char*));` will copy first 4 bytes into `ptr`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This code also is not complete, so no copy/move constructors have been implemented.

Comment: @KrystianS -- `std::memcpy(&ptr, data_, sizeof(char*));` -- No.  The first parameter is the address of a pointer, not a pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, and what I'm doing is I'm copying into the value of the pointer. It works just fine now.

Comment: @KrystianS Why do you need to do that?  Why not just return `data_`?

Comment: Because char isn't convertible to char*, and the pointer is made of 4 bytes (in this case).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, and `&ptr` is the address of `ptr`, so the call copies the first 4 bytes in the array `data_` into `ptr` itself (*not* where `ptr` points to). A union would be more traditional, but this should work okay as well.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but using a union would eliminate those `memcpy`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
  kstring(const char* str) 
  {
    size_ = std::strlen(str);
    if (size_ + 1 > capacity_)
       reserve(capacity_ + 1);
    std::strcpy(data(), str);
  }
```

This has a lot of issues.

First, you set `size_` to the size it's going to be immediately. But then if you look at `reserve`, it tries to copy `size_` bytes of what was already in the string.

Second, the amount you try to reserve is `capacity_ + 1`. But there's no reason to think that will be enough to hold the string you're about to copy.

This is probably closer to what you want:

```
kstring(const char* str) 
{
  size_t new_size = std::strlen(str) + 1;
  if (new_size > capacity_)
     reserve(new_size + 1);
  std::strcpy(data(), str);
  size_ = new_size - 1;
}
```

Notice we don't change `size_` before calling `reserve`, so it won't access out of bounds. And also notice that we tell `reserve` the correct number of bytes we need reserved.

Comment: Haha yeah, I figured that out. Thanks for your answer! Also, I didn't catch the first one. Thanks!